# In iOS, why do subviews wrap around to the other side when the superview is resized?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autoresize

Subviews that have their left side on the y-axis of their superview move
to the other side of the superview when the superview is resized. Is there
any logical explanation for this?

This is happening in both iOS 5 and iOS 6 on the simulator as well as on the
iphone.

This happens when the subviews have all the four margins set to flexible and
the width and height are **not** flexible like this:

[image: example uiview autoresizing mask]

**For example**, here is what the view will look like if the Resize button in the previous link is tapped only once:

[image: afterResizing]

This is the code that is executed when the Resize button is tapped:

```
- (IBAction)tapped:(id)sender {
    self.view2.frame = CGRectMake(self.view2.frame.origin.x,
                                  self.view2.frame.origin.y,
                                  self.view2.frame.size.width,
                                  self.view2.frame.size.height-1.0);
}
```

Comment: I too am having this problem. My workaround is to just set the X value to 1, and make the superview wider by 1 on each side (so it is still centered).